# Redirect 301 for all posts - migrate from joomla to wordpress

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

I moved my website from Joomla to WordPress. 
All I had to do was redirect 301 from the old address to the new one.
Regex always scared me :)

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/aktualnosci/(.+?)-(.*)\.html$ /$2
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, I would like to ask for help.

Link to the post on Joomla: https://my-domain.pl/aktualnoci/1360-energa-operator-rozbuduje-swoj-system-tetra.html

Link to post on WP: https://my-domain.pl/energa-operator-rozbuduje-swoj-system-tetra

Comment: Remove unnecessary spaces.

Comment: Your pattern contains `aktualnosci`, but your link contains `aktualnoci`